# HMAccessoryDelegate Method not called

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I want to get value of updatable characteristics for particular accessory.

So I am using `func accessory(accessory: HMAccessory!, service: HMService!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: HMCharacteristic!)` method.

But this method is not called. Another method from same delegate is being called. What should be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Enabled notification** for the characteristic in **viewWillAppear**.

```
for (HMCharacteristic *thisCharacteristic in characteristicsArray) {
    if ([thisCharacteristic.properties containsObject:HMCharacteristicPropertySupportsEventNotification]) {
        [thisCharacteristic enableNotification:TRUE completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error while enabling notification");
            }
            else    {
                NSLog(@"Notification enabled");
            }
        }];
    }
```

Also Disable the notification in **viewWillDisappear**